# Getting 422 error when trying to get github webhook deliveries using API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, github, webhooks

I am using the Github API to get the list of deliveries and I am using their API which is working fine for everything except then I try and get the list of deliveries.

Using their code:

```
const {
    Octokit
} = require("@octokit/core");

const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: token
})

octokit.request(`GET /repos/my_owner/my_repo/hooks/987654321/deliveries'`, {
            owner: my_owner,
            repo: my_repo,
            hook_id: 987654321,
        }).then(response => console.log(response.data));
```

This is the error I am getting:

`"hook_id", "owner", "repo" are not permitted keys.`
`Error Status: 422`

What am I doing wrong. I have used GitHub many times but have not seen such an error.

Comment: "`POST GET`" doesn't really make sense - a request can't be both.

Comment: @esqew, my mistake when pasting the code. I have now fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you got the code from [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/webhooks/repo-deliveries#list-deliveries-for-a-repository-webhook--code-samples) (as you didn’t specify in your question), you’ve replaced the curly-braced placeholders in the endpoint URL argument, counter to how `Octokit.js` actually works. From [`Octokit.js`' README](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js#octokitrequest) (emphasis mine):

> The 1st argument is the REST API route **as listed in GitHub's API documentation**. The 2nd argument is an object with all parameters, independent of whether they are used in the path, query, or body.

```
octokit.request(`GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/hooks/{hook_id}/deliveries'`, {
    owner: my_owner,
    repo: my_repo,
    hook_id: 987654321,
}).then(response => console.log(response.data));
```